# How do I change the content of a span element using javascript. .innerHTML method not working

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the content inside of a span element. I've tried :

```
    <span id='spanId'> content </span>

    document.getElementById('spanId').innerHTML = blah blah
```

This does not work and the console returns :

> 'TypeError: null is not an object'

Comment: Typo, forgot quotes, syntax error -`document.getElementById('spanId').innerHTML = "blah blah";`

Comment: have you checked if you have the element with this id? is the page rendered to the end before accessing the element?

Comment: Why don't you follow a good JS tutorial? This is a very common escenario

Answer (score -1):

blah blah is not a recognised value. Put it in between parenthesis "..." so it's recognised as a string and don't forget your semicolon.

`document.getElementById('spanId').innerHTML = "blah blah";`